# Canvas is not drawing

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am drawing on the HTML5 canvas. My javascript is correct, I rewrote it three times, but it stopped drawing on the canvas
Here is my code, and where it stopped drawing on the canvas

```
        //door
    drawRainbow.fillStyle = "brown";
    drawRainbow.fillRect(390, 210, 25, 90);
```

All the code before and after this point works just fine and draws on the canvas as expected. But the above code just won't draw

Comment: Your snippet looks fine, we'll probably need more context to solve this. Can you post a short example that can run on its own and just demonstrates the problem? Do you get any error messages? Also, are you sure you are not drawing something else on top of this rectangle?

Comment: check developer tools console for errors

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, my coordinates were way off and it was hidden by another rectangle